# Jquery Datatable's cells size increases everytime it is recreated

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using JQuery's datatable plugin.This is the configuration of table

```
            $('#myTable').dataTable({
                data: data,
                bFilter: false,
                bInfo: false,
                paging: false,
                destroy: true,
                columns: [
                    { 'data': 'ReportRank' },
                    { 'data': 'CategoryName' },
                    { 'data': 'ReportName' },
                    { 'data': 'PercentageChange' }
                ]
            });
```

Data comes through an AJAX call. On the click of a button I again fetch the data and recreate DataTable. But every time I recreate the table the width and height of table cells increase even though the data remains the same. Any clues on what is causing this behavior?

```
Update
```

Html

```
 <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-layout">
            <table class="table" id="myTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Rank</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Report</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#btnGet').on('click', function () {

    //$('#table').dataTable().fnDestroy();
    reportTrends.populateDatatable();
    }
```

populateDatatable method makes an ajax call and OnSuccess passes the data to the above mentioned configuration.

> Update 2

To temporarily resolve the problem I have changed the configuration to

```
columns: [
                    { 'data': 'ReportRank', 'width': '10%' },
                    { 'data': 'CategoryName', 'width': '25%' },
                    { 'data': 'ReportName','width':'50%' },
                    { 'data': 'PercentageChange', 'width': '15%' }
                ]
```

But I want some better solution and I'm still baffled about what's causing it.

Comment: I have updated the details.

Comment: It seems to work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nnt62t4u/). Maybe it's an issue with your data? Do you have HTML or plain text? Do you interact with the datatable in any other way (add styles, onDraw callbacks...)? Try to remove functionality until it works. As an aside, Datatables supports [ajax data sources](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax). You might want to look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

This will solve your problem. Even I faced the same problem couple of week back and this trick solved my issue.

Comment: It has given all cells equal width that's not what I desire.I want cell width to be determined by the cell content.